# oracle sql triggers trying to create auto filled description

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that when i:

```
INSERT INTO sightings (spotter_id, bird_id, latitude,
longitude, sighting_date)
    VALUES (2457, 901, -28.0, 152, '09-MAR-2016');
```

A description will in the sightings table will contain:

> ‘A bird of the species (BIRD-NAME) was spotted in the (X) , (Y) part
>   of the observation area’

**this what i have so far:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SIGHTING_DESC
BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
 REFERENCING NEW ROW AS New
FOR EACH ROW
    SET New.description = CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(‘A bird of the species ' bird_name ' was spotted in the ' latitude,
longitude ' part of the
observation area’
)));
END;
/
```

**im new to using triggers. am i on the right track?**

Comment: Does this trigger work? If not, what error are you getting?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, you're on the right track. Please edit your question and include the specific errors you're getting, or the results you're getting vs. the results you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you are inserting are available using the :new pseudorecord. 
So your trigger would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SIGHTING_DESC
BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    :new.description := 'A bird of the species ' 
                        || :new.bird_name 
                        || ' was spotted in the ' 
                        || :new.latitude || ','|| :new.longitude 
                        || ' part of the observation area';
END;
```

See the part about Correlation Names and Pseudorecords in this documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm

Comment: thanks! any idea on how i get the bird_name to show? because the insertion doesn't actually have the bird name just its corresponding bird_id. so i think i need something other then :new.bird_name

Comment: I guess that there is a bird table and you can get the name from that table using the Id.

Add a variable to the trigger that holds the bird name.

select bird name
into variable from bird_table where id=:new.bird_id

And use the variable in the string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SIGHTING_DESC
BEFORE INSERT ON sightings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    SELECT 'A bird of the species ' || bird_name || ' was spotted in the ' || latitude || longitude || ' part of the observation area'
    INTO :new.description
    FROM dual;
END;
```